# Подсчет стоимости по траченой воды и нахождение наибольшего количество по цене и и наименьшего

Tags: python, python-3.6

Всем привет нужна помощь в решении задачки:

1) пользователь вводит количество потраченных кубометров воды за 12 месяц и стоимость 1 кубометра

2) скрипт выводит стоимость за каждый месяц

3) после чего наибольшее количество по цене и и наименьшее

Пункт 1 я сделал скрипт предоставляю ниже.

P.S - нужна помощь в решении 2 и 3 пункта. Формула расчета стоимости кубометра я так понимаю вот такая (введенный кубометр * на введенную стоимость - например "23 * 19.88")

Скрипт:

```
print("Выберите один из пуктов меню:")
print("1 - расчет стоимости потраченой воды за весь год (по каждому месяцу.)")
print("2 - расчет стоимости потраченой воды за определенные месяца.")
print('')
menu = int(input("Сделайте свой выбор: "))

while menu < 1 or menu > 2:
    print("Вы выбрали пункт меню № {0} - он не существующий в этом пространсвенном мире".format(str(menu)))
    print('')
    menu = int(input("Сделайте свой выбор: "))

if menu == 1:
    print("Вы выбрали пункт № {0}".format(str(menu)))
    print('')

    arr_cubic_meter = []
    arr_cubic_meter_cost = []

    cubic_meter = 3
    cubic_meter_cost = 3
    count_month = 0
    count_cost = 0

    print('Вод кубометра воды за 12 месяцев')
    print('')
    for i in arr_cubic_meter:
        count_month += 1
        arr_cubic_meter.append(int(input("Введите использованный кубометр воды за {0}-вый месяц: ".format(str(count_month)))))

    print('')
    print('Вод стоимости одного кубометра воды за 12 месяцев')
    print('')
    for j in arr_cubic_meter:
        count_cost += 1
        arr_cubic_meter_cost.append(float(input("Введите стоимость одного кубометра воды за {0}-вый месяц: ".format(str(count_cost)))))


elif menu == 2:

    print('')
    month_selection = int(input("За сколько месяцев вы хотите сделать расчет потраченой воды?: "))

    while month_selection < 1 or month_selection > 12:
        print('')
        print("Такого месяца в календре не существует!!! Попробуйте снова =)")
        print('')
        month_selection = int(input("За сколько месяцев вы хотите сделать расчет потраченой воды?: "))

    arr_cubic_meter = []
    arr_cubic_meter_cost = []

    cubic_meter = month_selection
    cubic_meter_cost = month_selection
    count_month = 0
    count_cost = 0

    print('')
    print("Вод кубометра воды за {0} месяцев".format(str(month_selection)))
    print('')
    for i in range(cubic_meter):
        count_month += 1
        arr_cubic_meter.append(
            int(input("Введите использованный кубометр воды за {0}-вый месяц: ".format(str(count_month)))))

    print('')
    print("Вод стоимости одного кубометра воды за {0} месяцев".format(str(month_selection)))
    print('')
    for j in range(cubic_meter_cost):
        count_cost += 1
        arr_cubic_meter_cost.append(
            float(input("Введите стоимость одного кубометра воды за {0}-вый месяц: ".format(str(count_cost)))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На счёт

> Пункт 1 я сделал ...

Ваш код никак не будет работать. Достаточно взглянуть на эти две строчки:

```
arr_cubic_meter = []
for i in arr_cubic_meter:
    ...
```

Вот необходимый функционал, надеюсь по пунктам сами раскидать сможете.

```
cms = [int(input('Введите количество использованных кубометров воды за {0} месяц: '.format(i+1))) for i in range(12)]
cmc = [float(input('Введите стоимость одного кубометра воды за {0} месяц: '.format(i+1))) for i in range(12)]  
c = float(input('Введите стоимость одного кубометра при оплате за год: '))  

print('Затраты по месяцам (при оплате кубометра воды за каждый месяц)')
for i in range(12):
    print('За %s месяц потрачено %s' % (i+1, cmc[i]*cms[i]))

cbmc = sum([cms[i]*cmc[i] for i in range(12)])
print('За весь год потрачено (учитывая стоимость кубометра воды за каждый месяц): %s' % cbmc)

cbyc = sum([cms[i]*c for i in range(12)])
print('За весь год потрачено (учитывая стоимость кубометра воды при оплате за год): %s' % cbyc)

print(['Выгоднее платить за каждый месяц отдельно','Выгоднее платить сразу за год'][cbmc > cbyc])
```

И на будущее, постарайтесь не использовать мат на stackoverflow.

Comment: cbmc = sum([cms[i]*cmc[i] for i in range(12)])
print('За весь год потрачено (учитывая стоимость кубометра воды за каждый месяц): %s' % cbmc) - @dmitry klemenkov если не использовать функцию sum то эта строка будет выглядит вот так?:


cbmc = []
    
for i in range(12):
        cbmc = cms[i]*cmc[i]

    
print("За весь год потрачено (учитывая стоимость кубометра воды при оплате за год): {0}".format(cbmc ))

Comment: cbmc = 0; for i in range(12): cbmc+=cms[i]*cmc[i]